# Adding multiple fields to the same layer using QGIS graphic modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I want to add multiple fields to my layer using the qgis graphic modeler. I am trying to do this with the field calculator, but I´m unable to add all the fields to the same layer. I always end up with multiple layers that have only one of the new fields.

Is there a way to add all the fields (I need 8) to the same layer?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Refactor fields. Make sure to include all existing fields (for example by pressing Load fields from template layer), then press Add new field, to add new fields

[image]